# Force Login Page to Show in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a single claims provider in my Azure B2C custom policy - an SSO with our Azure Active Directory (AAD).

I can see that when there is only a single claims provider then B2C does not bother with presenting the B2C login page with only one button - rather it takes you directly to login with the only provider you have configured.

This presents me with the following problem because I, and many of my Company's users, am automatically logged in to the AAD. When I log out of the application that is secured by B2C the logic is to return to the B2C login page but instead it straight away **logs me back in again**.

What I would like is to log out and be presented with the login screen, rather than automatically being logged in again. I can change the app so that on logout you are actually redirected to a "you have been logged out" page, but this is not desirable.

How can I "force" the login page to show even though there's only one option available to the user?

Answer (score 2):

In OpenID Connect you add `prompt=login` to force authentication when redirecting to the B2C Policy.

There is an equivalent parameter for SAML. I don't know if the built-in flows will propagate this, but if you are doing custom policy you certainly can go back to the federated identity provider and force authentication again.

See the prompt parameter here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72654831/how-to-add-additional-parameter-to-my-azure-ad-login-link-to-modify-the-login-fu  How can i add it in my code?