# How to add additional parameter to my azure ad login link to modify the login functionality?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Right now I am working with the application which automatically logs in user through microsoft account after user enters the credentials once. This is how I am trying to call the microsoft login:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        // Load configuration settings from PrivateSettings.config
        private static string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
        private static string appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppSecret"];
        private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:tenantId"];
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        public static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = appId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        private static Task OnAuthenticationFailedAsync(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage,
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            notification.HandleResponse();

            string redirect = $"Home/Error?message={notification.Exception.Message}";
            if (notification.ProtocolMessage != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription))
            {
                redirect += $"&debug={notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription}";
            }
            notification.Response.Redirect(redirect);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                .Build();

            string email = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                string[] scopes = null;

                var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

                email = await GraphHelper.GetUserDetailsAsync(result.AccessToken);
                var account = await idClient.GetAccountAsync(result.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier);
                await idClient.RemoveAsync(account);//
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
            }
            notification.HandleResponse();
            notification.Response.Redirect($"Account/SignInAzureEmailAsync?email={email}");
        }
    }
```

```
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
```

I read this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) where is suggested me to use `prompt=login` which forces user to login every time they click on login button. I couldn't figure out how to apply this modification in my link. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RedirectToIdentityProvider` function to configure the `prompt` property

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("prompt", "login");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                
            }
        };
```